# Unexpected error in aio_context_set_poll_params() for QEMU emulator version 2.11.90 on Windows

Tags: windows, operating-system, qemu

I am trying this on Windows: https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/01-bootsector-barebones

```
E:\Code\MyOS\os>D:\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe boot_sect_simple.bin
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'boot_sect_simple.bin' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.

         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
Unexpected error in aio_context_set_poll_params() at /home/stefan/src/qemu/repo.or.cz/qemu/ar7/util/aio-win32.c:413:
D:\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: AioContext polling is not implemented on Windows

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

This also gives the same error:

```
D:\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -drive format=raw,file=boot_sect_simple.bin
```

QEMU version:

```
E:\Code\MyOS\os>D:\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -version
QEMU emulator version 2.11.90 (v2.12.0-rc0-11704-g30195e9d53-dirty)
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

NASM version:

```
E:\Code\MyOS\os>E:\Code\MyOS\nasm-2.13.03\nasm.exe -version
NASM version 2.13.03 compiled on Feb  7 2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the (release-candidate rc0) version of QEMU you are using: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1761027
It was fixed in the final 2.12.0 release. So you should upgrade your QEMU (either to 2.12.0 or to the more recent 3.0).

In general it's a bad idea to run with release-candidate versions unless you're using them specifically to test them before a full release.